# Store indexes after concatenating a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list like this,

```
mylist = [
    np.array([48.5, 38.0, 40.0]),
    np.array([61.5, 52.5, 55.5, 46.5]),
    np.array([35.5, 36.5]),
]
```

I want to find the index of the array, and the location of the specific value in the array together with the values in mylist.

I am able to achieve the last column with `np.concatenate(mylist)` but don't know how to handle the rest efficiently.

```
expected = np.vstack(
    (
        np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
        np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]),
        np.array([48.5, 38.0, 40.0, 61.5, 52.5, 55.5, 46.5, 35.5, 36.5]),
    )
).T
```

It can be read as i.e. 38 is in the first array (index=0) and it is the second element of that array (index = 1).

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do.  Can you rewrite your question to show us your input and what you'd like the output to be.

Comment: @FrankYellin The **expected** is what I desire to have as an output. And the last sentence explains my goal.

Comment: Well, your first array will be `[0]*len(mylist[0]) + [1]*len(mylist[1]) + [2]*len(mylist[2])`, and the second is `[range(len(mylist[0]))]+[range(len(mylist[1]))]+[range(len(mylist[2]))]`.  No need to go searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you ask, if this is really what you want.

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [
    np.array([48.5, 38. , 40. ]),
    np.array([61.5, 52.5, 55.5, 46.5 ]),
    np.array([35.5, 36.5])]

a1 = []
a2 = []
for i,l in enumerate(mylist):
    a1.extend( [i] * len(l) )
    a2.extend( list(range(len(l))) )

final = np.array( [a1, a2, np.concatenate(mylist)] ).T
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.   0.  48.5]
 [ 0.   1.  38. ]
 [ 0.   2.  40. ]
 [ 1.   0.  61.5]
 [ 1.   1.  52.5]
 [ 1.   2.  55.5]
 [ 1.   3.  46.5]
 [ 2.   0.  35.5]
 [ 2.   1.  36.5]]
```

Comment: You've missed `.T` at the end to get `expected` value like the OP mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hmm, I missed the call to vstack.  I will fix.

Comment: No worries. Nice answer. You could write `final = np.column_stack([a1, a2, np.concatenate(...)])`

Comment: Since that's the essence of your answer, I'll leave it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to find out len of each sublist in `mylist`. Then use that in [**`np.repeat`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to get "X" co-ordinate. Now, apply [**`np.arange`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) on each of the lengths to get "Y" co-ordinate and concatenate them using [**`np.hstack`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html). Now, just [**`np.column_stack`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) them together.

```
lens = list(map(len, mylist))
idx0 = np.repeat(np.arange(len(mylist)), lens) # [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
idx1 = np.hstack([np.arange(v) for v in lens]) # [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
vals = np.hstack(mylist) # [48.5, 38. , 40. , 61.5, 52.5, 55.5, 46.5, 35.5, 36.5]
out = np.column_stack([idx0, idx1, vals])

print(out)
[[ 0.   0.  48.5]
 [ 0.   1.  38. ]
 [ 0.   2.  40. ]
 [ 1.   0.  61.5]
 [ 1.   1.  52.5]
 [ 1.   2.  55.5]
 [ 1.   3.  46.5]
 [ 2.   0.  35.5]
 [ 2.   1.  36.5]]
```